# MySQL table in netbeans gets cleared at every time i build the application

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, glassfish, persistent

I am using netbeans 6.9.1, Glassfish 3.1. I am trying to write some values to the MYSQL table.

this works and the records gets saved to the table with no problem. But everytime when i restart glassfish or build the project all the saved data from the MySQL tables gets erased. How do i avoid this.

I have used Entity beans and Persistence to create table (auto generate tables)

```
@Entity
public class HotelVacancy implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Hotel hotId;
private int noVancies;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

 ...
```

How do i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have follow (or similar) row in your `persistence.xml`:

`<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>`

delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using hibernate??

Do you happen to have a property named hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in persistence.xml file??

If so, comment out, or remove this property completely from the xml file!

Answer (score 0):

Did your JPA provider create the database tables? If yes, he may still be recreating them every time you application starts. If your model is stable, disable this process.

Comment: See the answers by alexblum for EclipseLink and gred for Hibernate.